# How to get URL without required parameters

Tags: django

I have the following path in my URLS:

```
path('remove_order/<int:order_id>', RemoveOrder.as_view(), name='md_remove_order')
```

What I would like to do is get the URL WITHOUT specifying an order_id in my template. Like this:

```
{% url 'md_remove_order' %}
```

so it gives me something like this:

```
"remove_order/"
```

I will then pass this value to my Javascript where the order_id will be added dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re_path`

```
re_path('remove_order(?:/(?P<pk>[0-9]+))?/$', RemoveOrder.as_view(),name='md_remove_order')
```

So it will both work for `remove_order/` and `remove_order/123/`

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do that is to create another url that points to the same view but without the parameter:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('remove_order/<int:order_id>', RemoveOrder.as_view(), name='md_remove_order'),
    path('remove_order/', RemoveOrder.as_view(), name='md_remove_order_without_params'),
]
```

Then use that new url

```py
{% url 'md_remove_order_without_params' %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought of this, but having multiple PATHs just doesn't feel right to me.